# Netgear WNDR4000 open port 53

Tags: networking, router, security, vulnerabilities

Why is port 53 open on the WAN side of the router? And more importantly how do I close it?
Port 53 is not one of my forwarded ports.

Discovered by doing

```
nmap -pT:1-64 <my-external-IP> -Pn
```

Output:

```
[...]
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
[...]
```

How can I close that security hole? (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/listing-of-dns-vulnerabilities)

Comment: Yes, but why is the Port open on the WAN side of my router. I have no intention as to provide a public DNS Server.

Comment: The port is open on my router, not on my machine. And this a open port from the internet side into my router/lan not the other way round! DNS Request I would send to a DNS Server would still work if this port were closed.

Comment: Its not wise to post same question across multiple Stackexchange websites

Comment: I wasn't sure where it belonged to... But I am running the current netgear wndr4000 firmware. I found no options to disable dns features in there. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no suggestion because this behavior is normal.  Your question is the correct place for that information but your duplicate question is better at security SE anyways